# How to use apa6 man and have justified paragraphs

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs, apa6

I want to be able to use the `apa6.cls` class `man` but paragraphs are flushed to the left, and I want it to be justified.

Answer (score 2):

Journal submissions should be left untouched, since the publisher will most likely reformat things to suit their needs. [`apa6`](http://ctan.org/pkg/apa6) does issue `\raggedright` as part of the document class.

You could update the justification by loading the [`ragged2e` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) and issuing a `\justifying` wherever you want to have justified paragraphs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}% http://ctan.org/pkg/apa6
\usepackage{lipsum,ragged2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,ragged2e}
\title{Long title}\shorttitle{Short title}
\author{An author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[2]
\justifying% Revert from \raggedright to justified
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```